# Adding separate headers in my gridview

Tags: android, gridview, header

I'm loading data to my gridview using api call. I want to have 4 section headers and I want to load respective values to each header, I have 4 SubCategoryIDs. now all the items loading to same one grid

what is the way to do it? any help will be appreciated.

[image]

```
public class PFragment extends ListFragment implements OnTaskCompleted {

    GridView grid;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_grid_main, container, false);

        new PMenuAsyncTask(getActivity(), this).execute();

        grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try {
            List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1") && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("1") ) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                }

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1") && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("2") ) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                }

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1") && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("8") ) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                }

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1") && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("9") ) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                }
            }

            CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), descriptions, imageUrls);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with this process....there is no strait-forward way. you can use this [StickyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/tree/master/Library/src/com/tonicartos/widget/stickygridheaders).

or [Andorid-StickyHeaderGridView](https://github.com/guoGavin/Andorid-StickyHeaderGridView)

you can read some blog like this [Stickygridheaders](http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/) and [A Sectioned Grid for Android](http://velosmobile.com/2012/10/24/a-sectioned-grid-for-android/)..